# Spring DAO file, rowmapper not generic

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am working with Spring Maven, and trying to connect my SQL database with it.

When I try to use the rowmapper method, it says that it is not generic.

[image]

Comment: `RowMapper` is an interface anyway, you can't instantiate it like you are trying to .

Answer (score 0):

You can't instantiate `RowMapper`, you are supposed to create your own subclass to map rows with objects.

Let's assume your `Offer` class is this one :

```
public class Offer {

    private Long id;
    private String name;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(final Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Now let's assume that your `offer` table contains a varchar column `name` and a bigint column `id` .

Your custom `RowMapper<Offer>` class could look like :

```
public class OfferMapper implements RowMapper<Offer> {

    public Offer mapRow(final ResultSet rs, final int row) throws SQLException {

        Offer offer = new Offer();

        offer.setId(rs.getLong("id"));
        offer.setName(rs.getString("name"));

        return offer;
    }

}
```

Finally, use your custom implementation as a parameter :

```
return jdbc.query("select * from offer", new OfferMapper());
```

Comment: Thank you for this.. would it be better to use hibernate for database connection instead?

Comment: Hibernate has great advantages and the "mappings" are declared directly at your entity object level (your `Offer` object here) with annotations, sure give it a try.

Comment: @sumitslal : Also if the current answer answers your initial question, could you mark it as an accepted answer, thanks :)

Comment: @Arnaud How would you go about mocking the jdbc.query call using mockito, since such mappers are often private